# Extra white space on SlidingTabLayout bar in Android 7.0 N?

Tags: android, android-tabs, android-7.0-nougat

Just upgraded to Android 7.0 and all my SlidingTabLayout bars now have extra white space on the bottom. Not sure if this is intended by the Android team or not, but is there anyway of getting rid of the new white space?

[image: Extra White Space on SlidingTabLayout bar]

I am using code provided by Android which can be found here:

Sliding Tab Layout: https://developer.android.com/samples/BasicTransition/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html

Sliding Tab Strip:
https://developer.android.com/samples/BasicTransition/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabStrip.html

Here is a snippet of my layout code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_gradient"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

    <com.airsenze.wineinsider.controllers.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Thanks! Let me know if you need anymore information.

Comment: "Not sure if this is intended by the Android team or not" -- that is your code, not the Android team's code. You started with an Android example, but Android examples like this are not necessarily guaranteed to remain consistent across API levels. They are examples, not support library classes. In effect, you need to maintain your modified version of their code yourself.

Comment: Yeah I understand that. Not trying to blame the Android team for anything. I have been trying all morning to get rid of the white space, but nothing seems to work. Just wondering if anyone has a quick solution to get rid of it.

Comment: Why not setting your toolbar height to `wrap_content`?

Comment: There isn't really any reason. I changed it to wrap_content and everything is the same.

Comment: Created an issue on github, so maybe some will fix it: https://github.com/google/iosched/issues/218

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks to MihaiW, This happens when `distributeEvenly` is true. Just replace this line:

```
lp.width = 0;
```

With:

```
lp.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
```

in the `populateTabStrip()` method in the `SlidingTabLayout.java` class and your problem will be solved.

Comment: This works well for nougat devices! I wonder if it affects the already working previous versions though... Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Yes. I tested it on Android 4.0 to last version(7.0), it's OK.

Comment: While it fixes the initial problem, this solution add another one, the tabs are not distributed evenly anymore. I've replaced "lp.width=0" with "lp.width=ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT". This seems to work.

Comment: What really worked for me was this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35824027/1315405

Comment: @Afshin please help problem still not solved. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51806016/extraline-is-added-in-slidingtablayout

Answer (score 0):

Does your component style file has declare

```
 --<item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>--
```

I just find a similar bug with BottomDialog,I delete

```
--<item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>--
```

this line in my component style file otherwise the component will show 30dp above the real bottom.
I think you should check this file:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
```

delete item one by one to find which item acuse this bug.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will work for you or not but still try this in your layout. Set custom height (48dp) and set a condition for nougat. It unfortunately works for me:) .

```
  <com.airsenze.wineinsider.controllers.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="@color/white"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set max lines to 1 to tab's TextView.

There are two ways:

**1. Change SlidingTabLayout:**

```
protected TextView createDefaultTabView(Context context) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setMaxLines(1);
    ...
}
```

**2. Use custom tab layout**

For example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:paddingBottom="8dp"
              android:paddingTop="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/text_tab"
        android:maxLines="1" <=============attention==============
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Afshin given a excellent answer. I have runned on some issues with API lower than 25. This is maybe late answer but it could help someone.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    lp.weight = 1;
                }else{
                    lp.width = 0;
                    lp.weight = 1;
                }
```